# Can GPIO measure 3-10ms input spike?

Tags: gpio, measuring

I want to measure speed with one infra gate. The width of the bypassing object is known therefore I could calculate the speed. However the infrared gate would be interrupted only for 3-10ms. I understand raspi is not real time but it doesn't matter for me as far as I can get the exact time between low-high and high-low.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) library will let you reliably time gpio transitions to within a few microseconds.

The library itself is written in C but you can use any language you want to capture the data (the events are time-stamped at source).

Comment: Looks promising. I'll give a try.

Comment: @goldilocks That does NOT affect pigpio's time-stamping of gpio events.  The gpios are sampled by the hardware DMA engines which are pretty much insulated from system activity.